# I have a problem, cmd can't compile build.gradle

Tags: eclipse, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I want to code a Minecraft Forge mod in 1.16.5. I watched the Cy4 minecraft coding tutorial for coding my mod. I have downloaded the 1.16.5 MDK, and JDK 16 and I use Eclipse for coding. I need to open command prompt and type `gradlew genEclipseRuns --refresh-dependencies` and I then I get a `can't compile build.gradle` error message.

Here is the code in cmd:

https://gist.github.com/Cy4Bot/096f36ce775a5527734ef4e44cf48d77

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using JDK 17 which is incompatible with your Gradle version. Use JDK 15 or lower and your problem should be solved. Link for JDK 15 (You can also download JDK 11 as it's LTS):

JDK 15:  https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/15.0.2%2B7/0d1cfde4252546c6931946de8db48ee2/jdk-15.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe